# 1:n relation in OOP regarding to deserialisation

Tags: c++, oop

I've modeled two classes like this:

```
ClassA -- n:1 --> ClassB
```

ClassB knows nothing about ClassA (unidirectional relation). Now I'm currently writing a file loader for ClassA that *uses* (and does *not own*) a ClassB object.

Code-wise ClassA holds a pointer to ClassB, and that is where my problem arises: The loader is responsible for loading ClassA only and doesn't have access to the container that contains all the ClassB objects, so it's not possible to establish the relation.

A solution would be to insert a string member to ClassA that contains the id of the ClassB object, so the relation can be established later. The question is, however, if there are any other approaches that solve this problem. I don't need the id after loading anymore, therefore I'd like to leave it out.

**Example of a ClassA file that shall be loaded:**

```
Id: "some-id" # Irrelevant for this example. ;-)
ClassB: "some-classb-id"
```

ClassA holds **one** pointer to a ClassB object. The loader now deserialises ClassA and does **not** load any ClassB objects, instead only a relation is about to be established to an already **existing** ClassB object. The reason for this is that ClassB objects are pre-loaded and ClassA objects can be added during runtime.

The ClassB pointer in ClassA *may be NULL*, that's completely okay (it's an optional relation).

Comment: I don't know much about your problem, so your paragraph is kind of confusing about what you want.  ClassB knows nothing about A, okay, no problem.  The File Loader knows about ClassA but not ClassB; okay, I don't know why that really matters, as why can't it? But again, I don't know anything about the specifics of your problem.  ClassA holds a single pointer to a ClassB? Pointer can be NULL, but when does the relation get set? If it's a list of ClassB, then it just remains empty until later.  

Where is the string identifying ClassB come from? Why can't you establish the pointer then?

Comment: @Tank Again, please just clarify the problem, I can't really make out what you want or what you're trying to do exactly.

Comment: @leetNightshade: I updated the question. Hope this clarifies the problem more.

Comment: Well if ClassB is pre-loaded, and ClassA is being loaded in at runtime, why can't the Loader establish the relation after it loads ClassA? And if you don't want to save the ID, you could always hash it into an unsigned int. If you need to find a hash function, I've got a whole list of good ones.

Comment: @leetNightshade: The loader can't because it's atomic, it doesn't has access to a _ClassB pool_ to initialize the ClassB pointer in ClassA. And storing the raw id of ClassB in ClassA would be possible, but it's also overhead because the id is only needed for establishing the relation (which, when happening during loading ClassA, can be safely dropped). The current signature of the loading routine is like LoadClassA( filename ), and since ClassA doesn't _own_ the ClassB object (it's shared), there's nearly nothing the loader can do itself. ;)

Comment: @Tank Again, you can store the ID by hashing it and using a 32bit integer inside of ClassA, which isn't thaat much space is it?

Comment: @leetNightshade That's true, however in that case I'd always need to fetch the proper object when I need it. Currently there's a GetClassB() method in ClassA. By storing a (hashed) ID, this wouldn't be possible anymore (of course I could store both, but I really have A LOT of ClassA objects, so the memory consumption is doubled (ptr + ID) -- talking about 1 M+ objects in memory at the same time). I think I'll go with the callback idea, i.e. giving LoadClassA() a function pointer to a function that returns a ClassB ptr by ID.

Answer (score 1):

Only 2 approaches come to mind:

- The easiest approach would be to
  define 1 owner (ClassC) of the ClassB
  object, which then passes ClassB to
  the users ClassA.  This means adding
  dependency to another (new) class, but as far as I can tell, some class still has to distribute ClassB anyway.
- A bit more dirty would be that all
  ClassA's load ClassB and ClassB only
  loads the first time. but this would
  not allow to load ClassB more than
  once (solution could be to pass a new
  ClassB to the ClassA's when needed.

Comment: The first approach gets close to what I have in mind, however I don't want the loader to be dependant on one external interface due to flexibility. What came into my mind is to provide a callback function to the ClassA load routine that gets call to fetch a pointer to a ClassB object. What do you think?

Comment: @Tank: sorry, I'm not following.  We probably have a different view of the actual deserialization.  You'll have to take my answer for what it is: general approaches of deserialization with a shared object.  I probably miss the context to fully comprehend what you try to achieve.

Comment: @Tank: I missunderstood your question. It's not about a n:1 relationship, but about an n:m relationship where each ClassA can have a different ClassB based on the configuration file.  In that case the loader should pass the ID to ClassA at which point, ClassA should access the ClassB-manager (ClassC) to get the right ClassB based on the ID.  ClassA should not store it and I wouldn't use a Callback since the loader is accessing ClassA anyway (except if the loader is filling in the members directly).

Comment: It _may_ be an m:n relation, however like stated before, it's unidirectional, so the "n" in "1:n" is actually misplaced. ;) The reason I'm using the callback is to avoid storing the ID of ClassB, because it's only needed to establish the relation. It works like this: LoadClassA( my_callback ) → ..., class_a.b = my_callback( id ). I'm not sure if it's a clean approach, but it keeps establishing the binding rather flexible by not relying on any builders or factories.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are running into the famous [Object Relational impedance mismatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_object-relational_mapping_software)

There are many approaches and it depends on various factors. For example the size of the object graph you are loading, number of relations, type of persistence storage. It can get complex quickly.

My suggestions are:

- Do not mix persistence code with your business logic code. Those are separate concerns.
- Make use of an id/foreign key field to define the relationship (as you were leaning towards).
- Introduce a factory or more specific a [**Builder**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) that will act on the load side of an [Mapper](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html). Builders normally are uses for "complex cases", but you can get away with a Factory class too.
- The Builder will make use of you loader class (looks like ClassBFactory to me) to construct ClassB.
- The Builder will then need to get/have a reference to ClassB and then set it on ClassA if needed.

Some theoretical background:

Persisting objects can get complex and there are many "holes to fall in". Consider using a pre-build [ORM mapper tool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_object-relational_mapping_software).

But you can get away if you only have *simple* ORM use cases. Take a look at the **Object-Relational Structural Patterns** and **Object-Relational Metadata Mapping Patterns** by *"Master Fowler"* [here](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/index.html).

Comment: Very interesting facts and indeed clean and flexible. I'm just wondering if the effort of writing two more classes (the builder/factory and mapper) is worth it for just establishing one relation. In my current solution the caller who loads the code is responsible for that; as soon as there's only one place I actually use the loader, it seems to be a quick solution. Also this eliminates the need of a ClassB "manager". I'm really not sure about it. Do you know of data mapper examples?

Comment: I tend to stay away from Manager classes.. their roles are too generic and sometimes evolve to God objects that does too much and you loose flexibility etc. The java code on books.google.com should help. Look for "Patterns of enterprise application architecture By Martin Fowler"

Comment: Okay, thank you. Just to clarify, as I think I got you wrong: By "Do not mix persistence code with your business logic code. Those are separate concerns." you mean to create separate classes for the data representation itself? E.g. for ClassA the "model class" would contain the ID to ClassB as the string, whereas the "real internal code" would have the pointer?

Comment: Not really: It means your ClassA or ClassB should not reference Factory or loader classes. But ClassA or B may contain IDs. The model class you are referring to looks like a "**Metadata Mapping** Pattern".. separate from the DataMapper of Factory classes itself.